# Android Virtual Device (AVD) displays a black screen on start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

[image]

My **Android Virtual Device (AVD)** displays an **id** of **zero** on the first run on the screen's bezel i.e **0:emulator-name**. See screenshot above.

After **4-5 runs** of the same **virtual device** it displays the expected **id** i.e **5558:emulator-name**.

But previous instances of the same **AVD** will be running with black screen displays and they tend to consume system resources slowing down my entire machine.

My system specifications are as follows:- 
**AMD A8-4500 Quad-Core
8GB RAM**
running **Kali Linux 64bit Gnome**; a **Debian** distro.